# WxWidgets problem - Cannot convert from 'const char [1]' to 'wxString&w

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, wxwidgets

Environment : Visual Studio 2008 , wxWidgets 2.8.10 , Vista 64

Code

header.h

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class CSend
{
    CSend(wxString& name = "");
    ~CSend();
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

void main()
{
   CSend dlg(wxString("Hi"));
}
```

When I compile this program I get the following error

error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'const char [1]' to 'wxString &'

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Which wxWidgets version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Do you really wish to change the value of wxString name that is passed to CSend constructor? If not, change

```
CSend(wxString& name = "");
```

to

```
CSend(const wxString& name = "");
```

I don't know the wxString class, but I guess it has a constructor from char *. It allows you to create a temporary of type wxString that is used as a default argument for CSend constructor, but it can't be bound to non-const reference - only to const.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using a Unicode build of wxWidgets, change

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008->Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Character Set

to "Use Multi-Byte Character Set".

More details can be found here...

http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=403518

Answer (score 0):

instead of this line:

```
class CSend { CSend(wxString& name = ""); ~CSend(); };
```

try this:

```
class CSend { CSend(wxString& name = wxString()); ~CSend(); };
```

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted- it's a legitimate solution (though possibly not the best one)

Answer (score -1):

You just need to quote your strings with _() if you want them to be translatable and wxT() if you don't, this is for Unicode compatibility I think. In your case this would be:

`CSend(wxString& name = _(""));`

or

`CSend(wxString& name = wxT(""));`

As this is an empty string you might want to instead say:

`CSend(wxString& name = wxEmptyString);`

Comment: When I compile this code, I get the following error , "error C2440: 'default argument' : cannot convert from 'const wxChar *' to 'wxString &'"

Comment: You'd have to do CSend(const wxString& name = wxEmptyString) because wxEmptyString is a const wxChar*.  Actually, you need const in all these examples.